# Rotational Invariant Image similarity

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a reference image and I have to search for images in a test set which are very similar to the reference image differing only in rotation (apart from a minor distortion).

For this I have thought of a method (don't know whether it makes sense) that compares the pixel histograms in circumferential areas with centers coinciding with the center of the images (to take care of rotational invariance).

[image]

So then the task reduces to finding the best alignment between two circular arrays that minimizes the total sum of the absolute differences between corresponding elements.

For 1-D sequence alignment there are dynamic programming solutions but I think this problem is different. I was hoping to do this in a complexity of order of O(n) or O(nlogn) if possible.

Thanks

Comment: you are coming down from a general title such as "Rotational image invariance" and you restrict it to DNA sequencing - obviously you have a stick with it - there are general methods to detect rotation: e.g. you can use the "prominent-points" approach and since your matrix will only be rotational no loss - its no accurate but. you got distortion to begin with. I dont understand what line you are coming down with to bipartite matching: of course any problem with "match" in it could be thought of as such

Comment: @gpasch Sorry for the confusion, it is not equivalent to bipartite matching. The problem is to take care of rotational invariance with whatever approach is suitable. I have mentioned the approach that I tried, it may contain flaws. Can you elaborate on the idea of 'prominent points'?